Help with wiring 2x60AHV DC motor controller
The Project
I’m building a mobile cart utilizing two gearboxes to facilitate movement, each gearbox is driven by two 12V 775 motors. The cart will be used to transport my telescope and other equipment. For motor control, I’ve selected the Basicmicro 2x60AHV motor controller. I plan to control it wirelessly using an ESP32 with its Bluetooth capabilities and an Xbox controller.
Motor Specifications (for each motor):

Voltage: 12V DC
Maximum power: 380W (+/- 10%)
No-load current: 3.8A
No-load RPM: 21,020 RPM (+/- 10%)
Stall current: 130A
Stall torque: 0.7 N-m (6.2 in-lbs)(+/- 10%)
Output shaft diameter: 5mm
Weight: 0.806 lb

Question
I’m currently wiring the Basicmicro 2x60AHV motor controller and have some specific questions regarding the setup.

Bypass diode: Given that my cart will be moving very slowly (64RPM at the wheel) is a bypass diode necessary? I understand it’s typically used to protect the system from voltage spikes caused by the inductive load of the motors during a coasting scenario, but since I’m operating at low speeds, I’m wondering if it’s required for my application.
Pre-charge resistor: Could someone clarify the role of the pre-charge resistor in this setup and whether it's needed for my application? I want to make sure the system is properly protected during startup.
Battery setup: I plan to use a 12V 100Ah battery to power the system. Is this battery size sufficient for the motors and controller, or should I consider adjusting the battery choice?

I’d appreciate any advice on these components and how to wire everything correctly for reliable, safe operation.

Even at low speeds, the potential for damaging voltage spikes is still there, particularly when switching the motor on and off rapidly or when reversing the motor. So, a bypass diode is still a good idea to protect the motor controller from these spikes.

The 2x60AHV user's guide mentions one resistor and one diode.
That's R1 and D1 in this diagram:

You need both of them.  They are described in the section "Safety Wiring."

In all system with movement, safety is a concern. The wiring diagram below illustrates a system wired for minimum safety requirements. An external main power cut off is required for safety. When the RoboClaw is switched off or the fuse is blown, a high current diode (D1) is required to create a return path to the battery for any regenerative voltages. The use of a pre-charge
resistor (R1) is required to avoid high inrush currents and arcing. A pre-charge resistor (R1) should be 1K, 1/2Watt for a 60VDC motor controller which will give a pre-charge time of about 15 seconds. A lower resistances can be used with lower voltages to decrease the pre-charge time.

Both components are safety relevant and required.

D1 provides a way for current to flow back to the battery from the moving motors if the fuse blows.  You should include any power switch in this part of the circuit.
R1 prevents high current flow at power on.

